# VBA for making an array from the duplicate cells in selection and use this array as Autofilter criteria1

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a range and a table.

I want to check for duplicate items in a range and then I want to filter these items from the table... below is what I did but not working.

I have written a code for making a list/array/range of duplicate items in selection.

Then I pass this list/array/range duplicate to the Criteria1 of autoFilter. But its not working. it filters nothing.

```
' making of an array/ range of duplicates from selection
Dim Ary As Variant, cell As Range, i As Integer
i = 0
ReDim Ary(0)
For Each cell In Selection
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Selection, cell) >= 2 Then
    Ary(i) = cell.Value
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve Ary(i)
End If
Next
'If I put msgbox Ary(0) here then it shows me a value but overall the code is not working for autofilter && is it possible to use above code as separate function

'apply filter with duplicate values
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
          Ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like your array (`Ary`) will duplicate the duplicates, because although you test whether each cell occurs more than once, you don't check whether the cell has already been added to the array. If a value has already been  added (because you have now come across its second/third/etc occurrence) you don't want to add it to your array again. I haven't tested if the `AutoFilter` method gives unexpected (or no) results if the filtering criteria include duplicates, but it is something you could test for (if only to test as a source of error).

Comment: Have you thought about not using VBA? There is "Remove Duplicates" functionality built into Excel.

Comment: Removing duplicates is not my objective. My objective is to pick the items which are duplicates and then use them as filter criteria for the table.

Comment: @dmm You are right. `Ary` was containing all duplicate of duplicate values. I solved this issue now autofilter is working fine. Could you please let me know how can I pass the `Ary` as a function to my main  vba code. I know how to make functions and use them in main vba codes but `Ary` is an array. So when i give `Ary` as output to function then it gives subscript out of range error.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.exceltip.com/custom-functions-in-vba/create-vba-function-to-return-array.html

Answer (score 1):

Things Microsoft don't tell you Part 94...

The filter criteria values used in the `Autofilter` method must be specified as text strings, even if the column you are filtering on comprises numbers.

Change your assignment statement used for building the `Ary` array to

```
Ary(i) = CStr(cell.Value)
```

to ensure that the array comprises text strings.

Even better, additionally declare `Ary` as a string array

`Dim Ary() As String`

rather than as a variant so the intention for `Ary` is clear from the start.

There is a hint in the [documentation for the Autofilter method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) that numbers must be passed to the criteria arguments as text strings - see the third example listed in the documentation - but this requirement is not emphasised.

Answer (score 0):

### Return Unique Duplicates in an Array

- The most efficient (fastest) way to get the unique duplicate values into an array is usually achieved by using a dictionary: first you write all the values and their count to it and then you loop over the keys in the dictionary and remove each key whose item has a value of 1.
- To 'get' an array or any other result, you have to use a function which you will call from your procedure
  e.g. `Dim Ary As Variant: Ary = ArrMultiRangeDuplicates(Range("A1:A10,D5:d13")`.
- To 'convert an array to text' you can use this simple trick I used in your sub-example:
  `Ary = Split(Join(Ary, vbLf & "?"), vbLf & "?")`
- Before applying a filter, you need to check for and remove any previously existing filter.

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      If the 'Selection' is a range and if its cells contain
'               duplicates, it will use these duplicates to filter
'               the active sheet's Excel table 'Table1' in its 3rd column.
' Calls:        ArrMultiRangeDuplicates
'                   DictMultiRangeCount
'                       GetRange
'                       DictAddCount
'                   DictRemoveSingleCount
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub FilterByDuplicatesExample()
    Const ProcName As String = "FilterByDuplicatesExample"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub ' not a range
        
    ' Using the ArrMultiRangeDuplicates function and its accompanying procedures,
    ' write the Selection's duplicates to an array.
    Dim Ary As Variant: Ary = ArrMultiRangeDuplicates(Selection)
    If IsEmpty(Ary) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Using the Split and Join functions, 'convert the array to text'.
    Ary = Split(Join(Ary, vbLf & "?"), vbLf & "?")
    'Debug.Print Join(Ary, ",")
    
    ' Apply the filter.
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then ' remove possible previous filter
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
        
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Tests the ArrMultiRangeDuplicates function.
'               In the active sheet, enter some values in a range
'               starting from cell `A1`. Make sure there are duplicates.
'               In the Immediate window (Ctrl+G) see the results.
' Calls:        ArrMultiRangeDuplicates
'                   DictMultiRangeCount
'                       GetRange
'                       DictAddCount
'                   DictRemoveSingleCount
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub ArrMultiRangeDuplicatesTEST()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim Arr As Variant: Arr = ArrMultiRangeDuplicates(rg)
    If Not IsEmpty(Arr) Then
        Debug.Print Join(Arr, ",")
    End If
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      From a (multi-) range ('mrg'), returns its cell's duplicates
'               in an array.
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are excluded.
' Calls:        DictMultiRangeCount
'                   GetRange
'                   DictAddCount
'               DictRemoveSingleCount
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrMultiRangeDuplicates( _
    ByVal mrg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "ArrMultiRangeDuplicates"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    ' Return the unique values and their count, in a dictionary
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = DictMultiRangeCount(mrg)
    If dict Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    ' Remove the values that occur only once from the dictionary.
    DictRemoveSingleCount dict
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    ' Return the dictionary keys.
    ArrMultiRangeDuplicates = dict.Keys
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      From a (multi-) range ('mrg'), returns its cell's unique values
'               and their count, in a dictionary.
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are excluded.
' Calls:        GetRange,DictAddCount.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function DictMultiRangeCount( _
    ByVal mrg As Range) _
As Object
    Const ProcName As String = "ArrMultiRangeDuplicates"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim arg As Range
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aKey As Variant
    Dim acCount As Long
    Dim ar As Long
    Dim ac As Long
    
    For Each arg In mrg.Areas
        aData = GetRange(arg)
        acCount = UBound(aData, 2)
        For ar = 1 To UBound(aData) ' rows
            For ac = 1 To acCount ' columns
                aKey = aData(ar, ac)
                DictAddCount dict, aKey ' write to the dictionary
            Next ac
        Next ar
    Next arg
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Set DictMultiRangeCount = dict
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Adds a value ('Key') to a key of an existing ('ByRef')
'               dictionary ('dict') writing the number 1 to its associated item.
'               If the key already exists, it increases its item's value by 1.
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are excluded.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub DictAddCount( _
        ByRef dict As Object, _
        ByVal Key As Variant)
    Const ProcName As String = "DictAddCount"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
        If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
            dict(Key) = dict(Key) + 1 ' count
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In an existing ('ByRef') dictionary ('dict'), removes each key
'               whose item's value is equal to a whole number ('KeyCount').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub DictRemoveSingleCount( _
        ByRef dict As Object, _
        Optional ByVal KeyCount As Long = 1)
    Const ProcName As String = "DictRemoveSingleCount"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        If IsNumeric(dict(Key)) Then
            If dict(Key) = KeyCount Then dict.Remove Key
        End If
    Next Key

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```